# check if the ID exist (how can I improve my code)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

So how can I improve this code, this code works but it looks ugly I think

```
        cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE product_id= " & prod_idbox.Text & " "
        queryResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        If queryResult = 0 Then
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into products values('" + prod_idbox.Text + "','" + prodnamebox.Text + "','" + prodtypebox.Text + "', '" + pricebox.Text + "', '" + qtybox.Text + "', '" + unitbox.Text + "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Product Inserted")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Product ID already Exist")
        End If
```

Comment: That's not what SO is for. There are other sites intended for code review. If your code does what it is supposed to do then you have no question for SO.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no problem to solve.

Comment: Rule #1 - don't count just to determine if a row exists. That is very inefficient. A count will, in fact, spend the resources needed to count the rows. Use EXISTS or TOP 1. Rule #2 (which you've already been told) - parameterize your statements. You have an sql injection risk! Fix it NOW!

Comment: SQL access should be parameterised for many reasons.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you can try to insert that ID if it this define as UNIQUE in your database it will throw an error, if catch this error print your MessageBox.Show("Product ID already Exist")
would be something like:

```
try
 //insert
catch ( sql exception )
//print Product ID already Exist
```

Comment: Yeah, catching exceptions is valuable and all but this solution should be the absolute last thing on the list if you're looking for performance.  Exception handling does have huge overheads

Comment: didnt know that, thanks for sharing